# How to store each word of a txt file into a 2d array

Tags: c

```
int calc_stats(void)
{
    char in_name[80];
    FILE* in_file;
    int ch, character = 0, space = 0, words = 0;
    char str[30];
    int i;

    printf("Enter file name:\n");
    scanf("%s", in_name);

    in_file = fopen(in_name, "r");

    if (in_file == NULL)
        printf("Can't open %s for reading.\n", in_name);
    else
    {
        while ((ch = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF)
        {
            character++;
            if (ch == ' ')
            {
                space++;
            }
            if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
            {
                words++;
                strcat(str, " ");
            }
            else
            {
                strcat(str, ch);
            }
        }

        fclose(in_file);

        printf("\nNumber of characters = %d", character);
        printf("\nNumber of characters without space = %d", character - space);
        printf("\nNumber of words = %d", words);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My goal here is whever I find a word to store it in a 2d array but here I am comaring characters through the ch = fgetc(in_file) command. I need to somehow form a word and store it in an array.
Any help would be useful.

Comment: You cannot use `strcat` to add a single character. The second parameter must be a C-style string, in your case your character + the `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: What 2D array? Also, is there any reason why you can't use `fgets` instead of this?

Comment: A 2D is a two dimentional array such as char pinax[10][10]

Comment: where is the 2D array in your snippet?

Comment: Do you have to read it character by character? Can't you use `fgets()` or `getline()`?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Manolis lordanidis,

Here is the core code:

```c
// This is the place to hold your word (and its length).
static char word[256];
static int word_len = 0;
while ((ch = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF) {
    character++;
    if (ch == ' ') {
        space++;
    }
    if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0') {
        words++;
        // One word end. Now we need to put the word into str array.
        word[word_len++] = '\0';
        printf("Get: %s.\n", word);
        str[str_len++] = malloc((word_len) * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(str[str_len - 1], word, (word_len) * sizeof(char));
        word_len = 0;
    } else {
        // Hold your character into the word.
        printf("Push: %d.\n", ch);
        word[word_len++] = (char)ch;
    }
}
// Do not forget the last word.
word[word_len++] = '\0';
printf("Get: %s.\n", word);
str[str_len++] = malloc((word_len) * sizeof(char));
memcpy(str[str_len - 1], word, (word_len) * sizeof(char));
```

In my opinion, the 2D array may be a array of word, which type is `char*`, right? You can use a really 2D array. Do not worry.

In here I am using `malloc` function to ask for a array at runtime.

Every time, if the character is not space or something same, it will push the character to the array `word`. Then when it meet the space or something same or end-of-line (EOF), it will push the word to the `str` array.

I really hope it is helpful for you.

---

If you like using `malloc`, do not forget call function `free` :)

Comment: What type is str_len because I cant see it in your code

Comment: @ManolisIordanidis `str_len` is length of the array `str`. I define its type `int`, and init it as `0`.

Comment: Like `word_len`. A variable hold the index even after the last element.

Comment: @ManolisIordanidis Do you know state machine? I think if you use state machine, the program will be better.

Comment: No unfortunately.. :)

Comment: Do my answer help you? Are your question solved now?

Comment: yes thanks alot

Comment: @ManolisIordanidis Great, could you make my answer be approved please?